# Finding Pattern score

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, regex, c++14

> You are given 3 strings: text, pre_text and post_text. Let L be a
>   substring of text.  For each substring L of text, we define
>   pattern_score as follows:
>
> - `pre_text_pattern_score` = highest n, such that first n characters of L are equal to the last n characters of pre_text and occur in the same
>     exact order.
> - `post_text_pattern_score` = highest n such that last n characters of L are equal to the first n characters of post_text and occur in the same
>     exact order.
> - `pattern_score` = `pre_text_pattern_score` + `post_text_pattern_score`. For example, if L = "nothing", pre_text = "bruno", and post_text =
>     "ingenious", then
> - `pre_text_pattern_score` of L is 2 because the substring "no" is matched, and
> - `post_text_pattern_score` is 3 because the substring "ing" is matched.
> - `pattern_score` is 5 = 2 + 3  Your program should find a non-empty substring of text that maximizes pattern_score.
> - If there is a tie, return the substring with the maximal `pre_text_pattern_score`.
> - If multiple answers still have a tied score, return the answer that comes first lexicographically.  Complete the definition of function
>     `string calculateScore(string text, string prefix,string suffix)`
>
> Constraints:
>
> - text, pre_text, and post_text contain only lowercase letters ('a' - 'z')
> - 1 <= |text| <= 50
> - 1 <= |pre-text| <= 50
> - 1 <= |post-text| <= 50  (where |S| denotes the number of characters in string S)
>
> Sample case #1  text: "nothing" prefix: "bruno" suffix: "ingenious"
>   Returns: "noing"
>
> Sample case #2  text: "ab"  prefix: "b"  suffix: "a"  Returns: "a"

Could you please review this implementation and let me know is there any improvement I can do in this implementation?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<regex>

void  tokenize(std::string & text, std::vector<std::string>& text_prefix_tokens, std::vector<std::string>& text_suffix_tokens )
{
     std::string text_copy(text);
     int length =  text_copy.length();

     int i = 1;
     while( i <= length ) 
     {
          text_prefix_tokens.push_back(text_copy.substr(0, i));
          ++i;
     }   

     while( length-- ) 
     {
          text_suffix_tokens.push_back(text_copy.substr(length));        
     }        
}



std::string findHighestPattern(std::string & pre_text, std::string & post_text, std::string & text)
{
     std::vector<std::string> text_prefix_tokens;
     std::vector<std::string> text_suffix_tokens;
     tokenize(text, text_prefix_tokens, text_suffix_tokens);

     std::smatch matches;
     int post_text_score = 0;

     std::string post_result;
     for( auto &x : text_suffix_tokens)
     {
        std::regex pattern (x+"(.*)");      
        std::regex_match(post_text,matches,pattern);

        if(matches.size() > 0)
        {                                 
            int post_length = x.length();
            if(post_length > post_text_score)
            {
                post_text_score = post_length;
                post_result = x;
            }
        }
    }    
    int pre_text_score = 0;

    std::string pre_result;
    for( auto &x : text_prefix_tokens)
    {
        std::regex pattern ("(.*)"+x);
        std::regex_match(pre_text, matches, pattern);

        if(matches.size() > 0)
        {
            int pre_length = x.length();
            if(pre_length > pre_text_score)
            {
                pre_text_score = x.length();
                pre_result = x;
            }
        }
    }
    std::string result = pre_result + post_result;
    if(result.length() == 0)
    {          
        text_suffix_tokens.insert(std::end(text_suffix_tokens), std::begin(text_prefix_tokens), std::end(text_prefix_tokens));
        std::sort(std::begin(text_suffix_tokens),std::end(text_suffix_tokens));

        result = text_suffix_tokens.at(0);
    }     
    return result;
}


int main()
{ 
     std::string pre_text ("bruno");
     std::string text("nothing");
     std::string post_text("ingenious");

     //std::string pre_text ("b");
     //std::string text("ab");
     //std::string post_text("a");

     std::cout<< findHighestPattern(pre_text,post_text,text) <<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least a few places where you seem to be doing unnecessary extra work:

- First, even if not related to the sentence above, if you don't intend to modify a variable, pass it by `const` reference, not by simple reference.
- The most obvious unnecessary work is `text_copy`, even the name is a hint:

  ```
  void  tokenize(std::string & text, std::vector<std::string>& text_prefix_tokens, std::vector<std::string>& text_suffix_tokens )
  {
       std::string text_copy(text);
       // do stuff with text_copy...
  }
  ```

  If you only need the copy of a parameter, then don't pass it by reference, not by `const` reference before copying it, simply pass it by copy:

  ```
  void  tokenize(std::string text, std::vector<std::string>& text_prefix_tokens, std::vector<std::string>& text_suffix_tokens )
  {
       // do stuff with text...
  }
  ```

  That way, if someones passes a temporary `std::string`, then the move constructor of `std::string` will be called instead of its copy constructor. If you use a reference then make a copy, then the copy constructor will always be called, never the move constructor.
- Now, let's have a look at this piece of code:

  ```
  if(result.length() == 0)
  {          
      text_suffix_tokens.insert(std::end(text_suffix_tokens), std::begin(text_prefix_tokens), std::end(text_prefix_tokens));
      std::sort(std::begin(text_suffix_tokens),std::end(text_suffix_tokens));

      result = text_suffix_tokens.at(0);
  }
  ```

  First, I noticed that you sort `text_suffix_tokens` then take its first element. Since you never use `text_suffix_tokens` after that, it means that you did that to find the min element of `text_suffix_tokens`. If it is the case, then just do so:

  ```
  if(result.length() == 0)
  {          
      text_suffix_tokens.insert(std::end(text_suffix_tokens), std::begin(text_prefix_tokens), std::end(text_prefix_tokens));
      result = *std::min_element(std::begin(text_suffix_tokens),std::end(text_suffix_tokens));
  }
  ```

  Then I noticed that you inserted all of `text_prefix_tokens` at the end of `text_suffix_tokens`. So in other words, what you actually want to do is find the min element of `text_prefix_tokens` and `text_suffix_tokens` concatenated. However, concatenating is a bit expensive for what you're trying to do. Therefore, you could simply write this instead:

  ```
  if(result.length() == 0)
  {          
      result = std::min(
          *std::min_element(std::begin(text_prefix_tokens),std::end(text_prefix_tokens)),
          *std::min_element(std::begin(text_suffix_tokens),std::end(text_suffix_tokens))
      );
  }
  ```

Also, I have a remark about your spacing: it is too inconsistent. For example you sometimes put spaces after a comma, sometimes not; other times you put some when opening a brace but don't put any when clising it, etc... Your code would definitely be more pleasant to read if its style was more consistent.

Comment: Wow so algorithm turned from O(nlogn) to O(n)!!

Comment: I will work on the spacing too

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a correct solution of the problem. I run your program and got "noing" as output, which is not a substring. And the sample case 1 is not correct. If the inputs are ("onothinging", "bruno", "ingenious"), it should output "nothing".

The problem asks to find a substring L in text. What your program did is to calculate the pattern_score of text, and output the prefix & suffix that contribute to the score.